# Memory issues when using pandas for a huge dataset

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I have about dataset of N=10^9 pairs of integers. Each integer is nonnegative and less than 10^6. They are like

```
2 3 
2 4 
3 6
4 6
...
```

I need to group the data by one of the columns. Quite new to Pandas, I tried the following code but got a memory issue. Pandas seems to take huge amount of memory and then the code got killed (on a laptop with 16 GB memory. Any work-around?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time


N=10**9


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": np.random.randint(0, N, N),
    "B": np.random.randint(0, N, N)
})

starttime=time.time()
df.groupby("B")["A"].agg(list)
print (df)
print("Demo: it took this long to run pandas with N= {}, time={}".format(N, time.time()-starttime))
```

Comment: How much memory does your machine have? Pandas/numpy default to 64-bit integers. 10^9 * (8 bytes) * (2 columns) = 8 GB, and that's before the groupby operation starts. Under the hood, pandas groupby needs to allocate at least that much memory for the hash. What is the range of your integers? Could you store them in a smaller integer type? You also might try timing the groupby operation separately from the agg, or timing each of the functions in agg separately to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Each integer is less than 10^6 in my case. With 16G memory.